# La ejecucion del programa no entra en el foreach

Tags: java, iteraciones

Buenas estoy aprendiendo a usar el bucle foreach en java pero no consigo que mi programa entre dentro, espero que me podais dar alguna pista, gracias.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;import java.util.Scanner;
public class Taller {

private ArrayList<Vehiculo> listaVehiculos2;
public Taller() {//C

    listaVehiculos2=new ArrayList<Vehiculo>();
}
public void altaVehiculo(Scanner in) {  
    int codigo; //A
    String nombre;
    boolean existe = false; 

        System.out.println("Introduce un codigo"); 
        codigo=in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Has introducido "+codigo);

for ( Vehiculo vehiculo : listaVehiculos2) {    
    if (vehiculo.getCodigo()==codigo); {
        existe = true;
    }
    if (existe) {
        System.out.println("ya existe");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Alta de vehiculo");
                //voy pidiendo datos del objeto
        nombre=in.next();
        System.out.println("Se ha dado de alta un vehiculo");   
    }   
}




}
```

Esta es la clase del vehiculo

```
public class Vehiculo {
//A
    int codigo;
    String nombre;


    public Vehiculo(int codigo, String nombre) {
        //this.codigo = cont;
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.nombre = nombre;

    }



    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vehiculo [codigo=" + codigo + ", nombre=" + nombre + "]";
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

}
```

Comment: Si la lista `listaVehiculos2` está vacía, no entrará al `foreach`, asegúrate que tu `listaVehiculos2` tenga elementos agregados. La forma en que los agregas es con el método `add`, si no lo has hecho, esa es la razon.

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero la idea que tengo en  mente es pedir el código comprobar si el código existe con un bucle foreach y si no existe  que me pida por teclado rellenar los datos. ¿Se puede hacer?.

Comment: Claro que sí. Solamente que no puedes comprobar la lista si esta lista está vacía. Primero debes rellenar esa lista con los vehiculos y luego iterarla por medio del bucle `foreach`

Comment: ¿En qué lista almacenas tus vehículos que ya fueron registrados? Desde este punto, sería bueno que agregues más código que ya hayas hecho donde indiques los pasos que realizas para hacer el procedimiento.

Comment: Es que lo que yo queria era iniciar la lista vacia y  que me pida todos los datos por teclado, entonces que el bucle en la primera vuelta compruebe que el codigo esta libre pero que en la segunda ya me diga que ese vehiculo ya existe. No se si me explico bien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

Básicamente ya tienes tu programa, únicamente te hacen falta dos cosas:

1. Asignar los datos a un nuevo vehículo.
2. Agregar el nuevo vehículo a la lista.

---

**1. Asignar los datos a un nuevo vehículo:**

En el código que publicaste, tienes todos los datos necesarios para crear un nuevo vehículo, sin embargo, no has creado la instancia como tal del vehículo, es decir, no existe "físicamente" dicho vehículo. Para esto, has creado una variable booleana, que comprueba si el vehículo existe o no, lo que debes hacer es crear la nueva instancia en caso de no existir:

```
for ( Vehiculo vehiculo : listaVehiculos2) {    
    if (vehiculo.getCodigo() == codigo); {
        existe = true;
    }

    if (existe) {
        System.out.println("ya existe");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Alta de vehiculo");

        nombre = in.next(); // Ingresas el nombre del vehiculo

        Vehiculo nuevo = new Vehiculo(codigo, nombre); // el codigo ya lo habias ingresado

        System.out.println("Se ha dado de alta un vehiculo");   
    }   
}
```

De esta manera, el vehículo ya existiría "físicamente" sin embargo, aún no lo has agregado a la lista.

**2. Agregar el nuevo vehículo a la lista.**

Para finalizar, únicamente necesitas llamar el método `add` de tu lista:

```
listaVehiculos2.add(nuevo);
```

También puedes agregarlo más rápidamente de la siguiente manera:

```
listaVehiculos2.add(new Vehiculo(codigo, nombre));
```

Tu código debería verse así:

```
for ( Vehiculo vehiculo : listaVehiculos2) {    
    if (vehiculo.getCodigo() == codigo); {
        existe = true;
    }

    if (existe) {
        System.out.println("ya existe");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Alta de vehiculo");

        nombre = in.next(); // Ingresas el nombre del vehiculo

        listaVehiculos2.add(new Vehiculo(codigo, nombre));

        System.out.println("Se ha dado de alta un vehiculo");   
    }   
}
```

**ADVERTENCIA**

Si ya has probado el código, te darás cuenta que es común que te lance una excepción, específicamente [ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html), la cuál indica que no es posible modificar (en este caso agregar un nuevo elemento) a una colección (lista) mientras dicha lista se está iterando.

Para evitar esto, tienes dos opciones:

1. Aprovechar tu variable booleana para verificar si existe el vehiculo, y realizar las operaciones **fuera** del `for`.
2. Crear una copia de tu lista al momento de iterarla.

Te explico un poco:

En el caso número 1, podrías aprovechar tu variable para únicamente verificar si existe o no, algo similar a esto:

```
for ( Vehiculo vehiculo : listaVehiculos2) {    
    if (vehiculo.getCodigo() == codigo); {
        existe = true;
        break; // detiene la ejecución del bucle para continuar
    }
}

if (existe) {
    System.out.println("ya existe");
} else {
    System.out.println("Alta de vehiculo");

    nombre = in.next(); // Ingresas el nombre del vehiculo

    listaVehiculos2.add(new Vehiculo(codigo, nombre));

    System.out.println("Se ha dado de alta un vehiculo");   
}
```

Así obtienes el resultado esperado.

En el caso número 2, podrías crear una copia de tu lista al momento de iterarla, sin embargo, esto no se recomendaría en caso de que la lista sea demasiado grande, la ventaja es que podrías mantener el mismo código sin tener que modificarlo mucho:

```
for ( Vehiculo vehiculo : new ArrayList<>(listaVehiculos2)) { // Aqui se crea la copia
    if (vehiculo.getCodigo() == codigo); {
        existe = true;
    }

    if (existe) {
        System.out.println("ya existe");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Alta de vehiculo");

        nombre = in.next(); // Ingresas el nombre del vehiculo

        listaVehiculos2.add(new Vehiculo(codigo, nombre));

        System.out.println("Se ha dado de alta un vehiculo");   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Ahora si! muchas gracias me ha servido!